# Learning Python stuck on a lab

Tags: python

okay long story short, I'm total beginner to python, stuck on this assignment question (condescending lab calls it easy and says it will take 10 min to solve, cant say I agree)

basically I have to take this string, and double the size while keeping the proportions, (edit, the course requires this to be done using \n,end or sep)

I also have to replicate this arrow and get it to appear side by side, it says using string *2 will give me the right answer, but it isnt working, incredibly frustrated, could use some help

```
print("    *")
print("   * *")
print("  *   *")
print(" *     *")
print("***   ***")
print("  *   *")
print("  *   *")
print("  *****")
```

I was able to get it all into one string using the \n

```
print("    *\n   * *\n  *   *\n *     *\n***   ***\n  *   *\n  *   *\n  *****")
```

so at least I figured out that part

Comment: Please format your code properly and post what you've tried

Comment: How can `string*2` not work? It does exactly that: `string = '*'; print (string*2)` prints out `**`. You must have done something wrong in that code that you are not showing.

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

Before you double each string, you need to pad them on the right so they're all the same length. Otherwise, the pieces of the second arrow won't be lined up properly.

```
print("    *     "*2)
print("   * *    "*2)
print("  *   *   "*2)
print(" *     *  "*2)
print("***   *** "*2)
print("  *   *   "*2)
print("  *   *   "*2)
print("  *****   "*2)
```

Comment: MUCH APPRECIATED this worked, I tried the *2 but I didn't pad it hence why my output was messed up

Answer (score 1):

Barmar has the answer for the arrow duplication part of your question. For increasing the size of the arrow, you need to join the string with a space like so:

```
print("  ".join("    *    \n   * *   \n  *   *  \n *     * \n***   ***\n  *   *  \n  *   *  \n  *****  "))
```

Check https://ideone.com/8Pp8Eu

Comment: The tip of the arrow appears to be off by 1.

Comment: I appreciate the solution, though i've never used the join function, the course so far has only mentioned the sep, end, and \n is there any way to do it with just these?

Comment: Hm. Edit your question and add that you want a solution using sep, end, and \n!

Comment: No `join` eh? Too bad -- `print ('\n'.join([2*((' '*((width-len(p))//2)) + p + (' '*((width-len(p))//2))) for p in parts]))` works just dandy (where `parts` is the obvious `[x.strip() for x in "    *\n   * *\n  *   *\n *     *\n***   ***\n  *   *\n  *   *\n  *****".split('\n')]` and `width` is just a `max` for the part lengths).